# Simple search with MVC, problems with View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

My SearchUsers View looks as such :

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.Label("Search Users:" %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBox("keyword") %>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<%} %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            TITLE
        </th>
        <th>
            FIRSTNAME
        </th>
        <th>
            LASTNAME
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("GetProfile", "User", new { username=item.USERNAME }) %>
            |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("UpdateProfile", "User", new { username=item.USERNAME })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.TITLE) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.FIRSTNAME) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LASTNAME) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

An exception is thrown at the line that goes :

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
```

I want the model to bind with data only after I perform a search, but it seems to try to bind data when I first access this view. How do I prevent this?

My Controller is as such :

```
        public ActionResult SearchUsers()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchUsers(FormCollection collection)
    {
        DBServiceLinq db = new DBServiceLinq();
        Acctinfo acct = new Acctinfo();
        acct = db.SearchUsers(collection["keyword"]);
        return View(acct);

    }
```

My SearchUsers Method looks as such :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Acctinfo SearchUsers(string keyword)
    {
        var q = from acctinfo in db.Acctinfos
                where acctinfo.USERNAME.Contains(keyword)
                select acctinfo;
        Acctinfo a = new Acctinfo();
        a = q.First();
        return a;

    }
```

Comment: LINQ deferred execution enumerating the sequence only when Model is accessed, probably. ToList() in the controller?

Comment: Added how my controller / methods look like. Where did i go wrong? @bzlm

Comment: If you change it to `acct = db.SearchUsers(collection["keyword"]).ToList();` you'll hit the error in the controller. [Read up on *deferred execution* in LINQ.](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c16935) You are correct in your assumption that the actual search is performed when the view is rendered, which goes against the principles of the responsibilities of the Model, the View and the Controller.

Comment: How would i go about remedying it? Intellisense for .ToList() doesn't show

Comment: @valianthx add System.linq in your usings list

Comment: That reference has been there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the exectipon is a null reference exeception, maybe the first time you set the view from:

```
public ActionResult SearchUsers()
{
    return View();
}
```

Your model is null. Assuming your model would be a List that would be created in the constructor of your model have you tried

```
return (new MyModel());
```

Anyway in your view just before the foreach you can check if model is null or not

```
<% if(Model != null) {
   foreach(....)
```

**Update:**

Also your method that react to the post should return a list

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchUsers(FormCollection collection)
{
    DBServiceLinq db = new DBServiceLinq();
    IList<Acctinfo> acct = db.SearchUsers(collection["keyword"]);
    return View(acct);
}


[WebMethod]
public IList<Acctinfo> SearchUsers(string keyword)
{
    var q = (from acctinfo in db.Acctinfos
            where acctinfo.USERNAME.Contains(keyword)
            select acctinfo).ToList();        
    return q;
}
```

Comment: I did try this way earlier, and i get this exception message:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Practical4Redone.Acctinfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Practical4Redone.Acctinfo]'.

Comment: So you are expecting a list of acctinfo. Then return an empty list of that. Return View(new List<AcctInfo>());

Comment: With respect to that bit, My column headers show but when i click on Search, i still get the same exception compared to previously where the column headers wouldn't even show. Sorry, but im a little dense with the whole MVC concept /facepalm

Comment: Because your action responding to post should return the same model. So like suggested in other comment try returning a list. From your code change to : a = q.ToList(); and remeber the using System.Linq on top of your cs file

Comment: I tried that, but i get this exception now: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Practical4Redone.Acctinfo>' to 'Practical4Redone.Acctinfo'

Comment: Guess I was not clear. You have to return a List because it is what you ask in your view. So also the action method that answer your post should return a list. In your code you return a single instance of acctinfo. You must correct your functions. Update the answer to be more clear

Comment: Thank you so much Iridio, you have no idea how relieving this is. Your help has bee invaluable!!